# stpes required to install apache cassandra-3.11.x as as a service on centos offline?

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-3.0

I want to install apache cassandra as a process.

can we make a process as a service then what things need to be done?

or do i have to proceed with rpm installation of cassandra package?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

below steps required to install cassandra as a service-

1. download the latest rpm package-

   https://www.apache.org/dist/cassandra/redhat/311x/cassandra-3.11.4-1.src.rpm
2. go to the directory where you have downloaded the rpm package and run below commands as a super user-

sudo rpm -ivh cassandra-3.11.4-1.src.rpm

this will do the installation and creation of cassandra directory at different location systemwise. some of the important directory you can go and check with default configuration (no changes in cassandra.yaml file)-

data dir- /var/lib/cassandra/

log dir- /var/log/cassandra/

configuration dir- /etc/cassandra/conf/

3. now run the command

sudo service cassandra start

this will start cassandra as a service. you can check the nodetool status for more information.